# enable swatches not displayed as crossed out when out of stock?

Tags: configurable-swatches, magento2.3.4

I just want to remove crossed out lines and enable Swatches when the sample product is out of stock. This is already working on Magento 2.3.2 but after update to 2.3.4, its shows crossed outline. can anyone help me with this problem?
[image]